# Fitting a GARCH model and forecast using validation set approach In R

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, garch, volatility-forecasting

I have seperated the data into training and testing data. Then I fitted this simple garch model for training data as follows,(using rugarch package)

```
require(rugarch)   
 model_g<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                      mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE), 
                      distribution.model = "norm")
    ugfit=ugarchfit(spec = garch_spec,data = retu_train)
```

Then i want to get the fitted values based on the test data. I used the ugarchforecast function as follows,

```
ugarchforecast(ugfit,data=retu_test)
```

But the output is as follow which does not contain fitted values based on test data.

```
*------------------------------------*
*       GARCH Model Forecast         *
*------------------------------------*
Model: sGARCH
Horizon: 10
Roll Steps: 0
Out of Sample: 0

0-roll forecast [T0=0230-01-01]:
       Series  Sigma
T+1  0.004748 0.1175
T+2  0.004702 0.1173
T+3  0.004657 0.1173
T+4  0.004615 0.1172
T+5  0.004574 0.1172
T+6  0.004535 0.1171
T+7  0.004498 0.1171
T+8  0.004463 0.1169
T+9  0.004429 0.1169
T+10 0.004396 0.1168
```

I am kind of new to garch modeling . So it is highly appreciated if someone can help me figure out how to get the fitted values based on test data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fitted values can be values for the return or for the conditional variance of the returns. In your case the fitted values for the returns will be 0 due to your choice of specification for mean.model ARMA(0,0) and no inclusion of a mean. You can retrieve them from the model fit using the code

`ugfit@fit$fitted.values`

or equivalent

`fitted(ugfit)`

The fitted values for the variance you get using the code

`ugfit@fit$var`

or if you prefer the fitted standard deviation

`ugfit@fit$sigma`

or equivalent

`sigma(ugfit)`

you can always inspect an object using `str()` function so take a look at

`str(ugfit)`

this is what I did to see how the fitted values, sigma and var are stored in the fit object (which is S4 class hence the use of @ ).

Here is a complete example but with some other data since I do not have the data you are using and also there's a minor error in the code you posted

```
require(rugarch)
data(sp500ret)

garch_spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model =     "sGARCH", garchOrder = c(1, 1)), 
                  mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0, 0), include.mean = FALSE), 
                  distribution.model = "norm")

ugfit <- ugarchfit(spec = garch_spec,data = sp500ret)
ugfit@fit$fitted.values
ugfit@fit$var
ugfit@fit$sigma
str(ugfit)
```

You can check out the nice blog on the rugarch package by the author of the package [rugarch](http://www.unstarched.net/r/rugarch/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So if  i need to find the forecast for next 10 days, i can use ,     ugarchforecast(ugfit,n.ahead = 10)) and extract the "series" column of that output. isnt it ?

Comment: The OP question is about generation of conditional variance on the validation set not training set.

Comment: Maybe you're right. But conditional variance on the validation set is not called 'fitted values' which is also what OP explicitly says. In case you are right read the answer given by Richard Hardy dealing with forecasts.

Answer (score 3):

`ugarchforecast` is not using the `data` argument if you supply a fitted model as the first argument; you can see this by reading the help file for `ugarchforecast`. When you supply the data `retu_test` via `ugarchforecast(ugfit,data=retu_test)`, the data is ignored and the forecast is based on the fitted model and the last few data points in the training set `retu_train`. The trick is, GARCH models are autoregressive in the sense that they do not need new data to predict multiple steps ahead; the fitted model and the last few observations from the training data are enough to make forecasts.

What you could do instead is rolling-window forecasting.

- Take a single time series of length $T$.
- Estimate the model on the first $T-k$ data points (window $[1,T-k]$) and forecast the next data point.
- Then roll the estimation window from $[1,T-k]$ to $[2,T-k+1]$ and forecast the next data point.
- Keep rolling until you run out of data.
- Collect the $k$ forecasts and compare them to the actual realization to assess forecasting performance.

This assesses one-step-ahead forecasting performance.
You can forecast a few steps ahead instead of one if you are interested in a different forecast horizon.
You can also assess how well a model trained on one time series works on another time series. You would take an estimated model (defined by all of its coefficients plus the distributional assumption) and "filter" a new series and produce forecasts.

Point forecasts are in the column `Series`.
Forecasts of the conditional variance are in the column `Sigma`.

Comment: Reading this post late, but I have a question. If you were not to roll, but predict multiple steps ahead, this would propagate a lot of error, right (especially is betas are close to 1)? So, what you are suggesting the rolling alternative, is to avoid this?

Comment: @deblue, regarding the first question, yes, that would propagate the error(s). Regarding the second question, I do not understand it; could you rephrase?

Comment: You are suggesting a rolling-window forecasting whereby one would refit given one more data point each day and forecast the next. Is this a way to avoid the error propagation that would otherwise arise? I am guessing parameters would not change a lot from day to day if the model is fit properly ..

Comment: @deblue, error propagation depends on the forecast horizon, and that is tangential to the use of rolling windows. If you are interested in forecasting $h>1$ steps ahead with a GARCH(1,1) model, you will encounter error propagation regardless of whether you use rolling windows or not.